# Problem with WooCommerce and Lost password page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm new to website development with Wordpress, and I've come with an issue I'm struggling to solve. While using WooCommerce, I wanted to treat the lost password procedure in a separated webpage. Therefore, I decided to define a new shortcode for this lost password form, by adding the following lines to the functions.php:

```
function wc_custom_lost_password_form( $atts ) {
    ob_start();
    wc_get_template( 'myaccount/form-lost-password.php', array( 'form' => 'lost_password' ) );
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'lost_password_form', 'wc_custom_lost_password_form' );
```

Everything worked fine, but the problem is that the lost password form is not formatting properly. If you see its appearance ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKPKW.png)), the style of the input text and the button is completely different to the one the login and register forms are displaying ([2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYKht.png)). It seems that I'm missing something, but my knowledge is quite limited, so I cannot find a proper solution to it.

Anyone has an idea on what could be happening?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think you are either missing the woocommerce.css file that styles it or you should try to wrap your shortcode with a div that has class "woocommerce" since most of the default rules expect the woocommerce thing to be into something that has that class

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, Diego! I've actually used the div class woocommerce wrapping, and the results are still the same.